# How to add extra .h and .m files to Obj-C project

Tags: objective-c, xcode

When creating a project in straight 'C' I can manage to split lengthy code into multiple h/c groups without issues. However, while I've been dabbling in Obj-C for a few years now I still can't grasp the following fundamental issue (perhaps because of my old C-style thinking and great-grandfatherly age?), which has led to the habit of writing huge, monolithic files which are hard to read/edit etc. I've tried everything I can think of and spent weeks searching the net for answers, but all to no avail.

Just suppose I create an NSObject instance called 'AppController, which contains the required h/m files. The interface file is basically laid out like so:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface AppController : NSObject
{
    IBOutlets etc here...
}

method declarations here…

@end
```

while the implementation file looks like so:

```
#import "AppController.h"

@implementation AppController

actual methods here …

@end
```

NOW suppose I want to add two extra h/m files called 'temperature'. In other words, I'm after four files in my project, namely:

```
AppController.h
AppController.m
temperature.h
temperature.m
```

I get that I'd have to #import the temperature interface file into my main AppController implementation file of course, but would I also need to create them as NSObject classes? These templates come with their own pre-written references to super etc. which cause all kinds of compiler issues and even more confusion.

Perhaps following my super-basic code snippet examples above, how would the temperature.h, temperature.m (and AppController.m) files be laid out so they can talk to each other? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you expand on what's in `temperature.h`? Is it a class? Is it a bunch of free functions? What are the circumstances under which things in `temperature.m` need to know about `AppController`? That may be a sign of unnecessary coupling of classes (or other things).

Comment: @user1118321 Replied to your request for clarification an hour or more ago, but it hasn’t shown up. Just in case you didn’t get it, they are just “free” functions requiring no special additional class like NSImage etc.. Just want to convert these C-style functions to Obj-C methods and place in separate h/m group to tidy up and make AppController.m less confusing to read. Also gets around problem of sending back [self addToTERecord:(NSString*)passedStr];  to AppController. HTH.

Comment: I apologize. I was away from my computer for several days. I've added a response below.

Comment: No apology necessary, as the fault lay entirely with me. When I posted the requested info it just vanished into the ether rather than appear on this page so I probably did something wrong. Just wondered whether it had gone to you as a personal message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `temperature` files contain free functions, there's nothing more you need to do. You can simply call C functions from within Objective-C classes. If you want to make a class out of them, you can do that, too. It doesn't have to inherit from `NSObject`, but it can be useful to do that because it allows you to call various `NSObject` methods on it, such as `-respondsToSelector:`, `-isKindOfClass:` or `-performSelector:`.

Comment: I really appreciate your help and think I get it now. I marked your answer as accepted but message said "it doesn't change the publicly displayed post score because I have less than a 15 reputation".

Comment: You're very welcome. Welcome to Stack Overflow by the way! I hope you like it here.